# OpenCV(4.6.0) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, conv-neural-network

This is the error i'm getting

[image: This is the error i'm getting]

```
IMG_SIZE = 224
def read_img(img_path):
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
imG = img_to_array(img)
data.append(img)
return img
train_img = []
for img_name in tqdm(train['image_id'].values):
train_img.append(img_name + '.jpg')
train['image'] = train_img
```

** I'm just running a sample code i found in kaggle but it's not working for me**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code (formatted properly) and the errors as text and not as an image.   Take a look at that error.  It looks like it is having issues with reading that jpg image file.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre] and debug _your program_. you will get no help at all if you don't show some effort of your own.

Comment: @alibustami that will fail because the dsize argument must be a 2-tuple, not a numpy shape... and cv2.resize does NOT take anything called "`d_type`", nor does it take the `np.uint8` type passed to it in any way. and you're entirely wrong to poke at that place in the code. as the error says, `img` is empty. perhaps don't approach things as enthusiastically. you're confusing yourself and others.